# Fluent NHibernate - Map only a few classes in assembly

Tags: configuration, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

I have a entity project which holds about 30 classes and this project is used in several web applications. One application maybe uses all the 30 classes but another one only uses 3 classes. 
So my question is:
How can I add just the classes that a uniqe application needs?
My first thought was to add the names of the needed classes in app settings in web.config like:

```
<add key="MappingClasses" value="User,Application,News" />
```

And then split and loop in the configuration of the session factory.
But I really would like your input on this! 
What is the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can tell to your AutoPersistenceModelGenerator to Filter classes by some criteria.

e.q.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a filter for only including types which inherit from the IEntityWithTypedId interface.
    /// </summary>
    private bool GetAutoMappingFilter(Type t)
    {
        return t.GetInterfaces().Any(x =>
                                     x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEntityWithTypedId<>));
    }
```

So now you could read your config file and using reflection to create your filter criteria.